# How to keep track of various types of streaks

Tags: python

I am writing a script that watches an online coin flip game, and keeps a tally of the results. I would like to find a simpler way of finding out how many times the streak ended after three of the same results, four of the same result etc.

```
if result = heads:
headsCount += 1
headsStreak +=1

tailsCount = 0
tailsStreak = 0
```

headsCount is the total amount of heads results witnessed in a session, and the streak is just so I can display how many heads have appeared in a row. This is update by:

```
if headsCount >= headsStreak:
headsStreak = headsCount
```

My problem - I wish to keep track of how many times the streak ends at one, ends at two, ends at three etc...

A silly way I have for now:

```
if headsStreak = 1:
    oneHeadsStreak +=1
if headsStreak = 2
    twoHeadsStreal +=1
```

But it is very tedious. So is there an easier way to create the variables... for example:

```
for i in range (1, 20):
    (i)streak = 0
```

and then something like

```
for i in range (1, 20):
    if headsStreak = i:
        (i)streak += 1
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list to keep track of the streak counter. You will have to think about which index is which streak length (e.g. index 0 is for streak length 1, index 1 for length 2 etc.).

Initialize all list elements to  zero:
`l = [0 for i in range(20)]`
Then, whenever a streak ends, increment the list element at the corresponding index: `l[3] += 1` for a 4-streak.

Comment: What happens when there is a streak of more than 20?

Comment: Sorry, meant to add that I'll only be interested in streaks up to a certain amount.

Comment: If you are interested in arbitrary streak lengths, use a dict or check if the current streak length is above your threshold and append additional zeros to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), You just need three variables,

```
from collections import defaultdict
current_streak = 0
current_side = "heads"
streak_changes = defaultdict(int)
```

Then store the values in a dictionary when the streak changes

```
if side == current_side:
    current_streak += 1
else:
    current_side = side
    streak_changes[current_streak] += 1
    current_streak = 1
```

Comment: With this, will I be able to then access how many times the streak ended at one, or two, or five? Eg   one in a row = 3 time, two in a row = 10 times

Comment: @pythonTron1 - Yep, streak changes will be a dictionary mapping the streak to a count of that streak i.e `{1: 0, 2: 5, 5: 7}` or individual counts via `streak_changes[2]` (would be 5)